# IIS7 Staticfilehandler changing GIF file colors

Tags: .net, iis-7, compression, staticfilehandler

Environment: 2 IIS7 servers, 1 appears to be compressing images the other is not, i want to turn off the compression.

I have a site running on two IIS7 server, when serving images from one server the GIFs look fine, when i serve them from the other instance, with the same files, the GIF color palette looks web safe or compressed or something, even jpegs look severely compressed but look fine when served from the other system.

Is there a compression setting somewhere that can change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a setting on a regular IIS7 server that would affect the color palettes.  Are you using the same client to test the two servers?

Comment: Firefox, comparing one tab to the other